# ¿ Por que mi DataGrid no me muestra los registros de mi base de datos (C# , SQL server)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

He estado intentando mostrar los datos guardados en mi base de datos en un DataGrid  realizado en C# en Visual Studio 2015 en una ventana WPF y hasta ahora no encuentro el error. Los datos se almacenan normalmente, solo no los llega a mostrar. Tengo proyectos muy parecidos, las unicas diferencias que hay entre esos proyectos y este, es el datetime y la cantidad de datos a almacenar. Fuera de eso todo es casi identico. Ya no se que detallar, es mi primera vez en overflow y  me esta pidiendo mas detalles por la cantidad de codigo. Estuve viendo en yt como mostraban los datos de un datagrid y su codigo es muy distinto al mio, y me cuesta adaptarme a eso. Pues igual lo intente y nada.

```
 public List<eDenuncia> Listartodo()
    {
        try
        {
            List<eDenuncia> IsDenuncia = new List<eDenuncia>();
            DateTime d;
            eDenuncia objDenuncia = null;
            SqlConnection con = db.ConectaDb();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Codigo_Aleatorio,Nombre,DNI,Categoria,Distrito,Provincia,Departamento,Fecha,Horario_Hora,Horario_minutos,Descripcion,Estado from Tabla_Denuncia ", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                objDenuncia = new eDenuncia();
                objDenuncia.Codigo_Aleatorio = (int)reader["Codigo_Aleatorio"];
                objDenuncia.Nombre = (string)reader["Nombre"];
                objDenuncia.DNI = (int)reader["DNI"];
                objDenuncia.Categoria = (string)reader["Categoria"];
                objDenuncia.Distrito = (string)reader["Distrito"];
                objDenuncia.Provincia = (string)reader["Provincia"];
                objDenuncia.Departamento = (string)reader["Departamento"];
                d = (DateTime)reader["Fecha"];
                objDenuncia.Fecha_denuncia = d.ToShortDateString();
                objDenuncia.Horario_hora = (int)reader["Horario_Hora"];
                objDenuncia.Horario_min = (int)reader["Horario_minutos"];
                objDenuncia.Descipcion = (string)reader["Descripcion"];
                objDenuncia.Estado = (string)reader["Estado"];
                IsDenuncia.Add(objDenuncia);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return IsDenuncia;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;

        }
        finally
        {
            db.DesconectaDb();
        }

    }
 //Esto ya es en otra capa
public List<eDenuncia> Listardenuncias()
    {
        return denunciadd.Listartodo();
    }

 // y este ultimo es en la parte de la ventana WPF

 nDenuncia denuncianegocio = new nDenuncia();
    public FrmDenunciarr()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Mostrardenuncias();
    }

    private void Mostrardenuncias()
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = denuncianegocio.Listardenuncias();   
    }
private void Bt_Enviar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string nombre;
        int dni;
        string categoria;
        string distrito;
        string provincia;
        string departamento;
        DateTime fecha;
        int horario_hora;
        int horario_minutos;
        string descripcion;
        int codigo_aleatorio;
        string estado;
        List<eDenuncia> lista;

        lista = denuncianegocio.Listardenuncias();
        //  codigo_aleatorio = denuncianegocio.generar_numero();
        nombre = textBox_Nombre.Text;
        dni = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Dni.Text);
        categoria = comboBox_Delito.Text;
        distrito = CBDistrito.Text;//ACA
        provincia = CBProvincia.Text;//ACA
        departamento = CBDepartamento.Text;//ACA
        fecha = (DateTime)dtfecha.SelectedDate;
        horario_hora = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Hora.Text);
        horario_minutos = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_Minutos.Text);
        descripcion = textBox_Descipcion.Text;
        estado = "No revisado";
        codigo_aleatorio = rnd.Next(100,984);



        string MensajedeDenuncia;
        MensajedeDenuncia= "CODIGO DE DENUNCIA : "; 

        MessageBox.Show( MensajedeDenuncia + (codigo_aleatorio.ToString()));
        MessageBox.Show(denuncianegocio.Registrardenuncia(codigo_aleatorio,nombre, dni, categoria, distrito, provincia, departamento, fecha, horario_hora, horario_minutos, descripcion,estado));
        Mostrardenuncias();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema que noto se relaciona a como instancias `eDenuncia` dentro del `while`, la declaracion de la variable de cada item que agregas debes realizarse dentro del loop y no por fuera

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    eDenuncia objDenuncia = new eDenuncia();

    //resto codigo

    IsDenuncia.Add(objDenuncia);

}
```

quita la linea

```
eDenuncia objDenuncia = null;
```

es importante respetar el ambito de las variables para que en cada iteracion tenga una instancia nueva, sino estas pisando siempre la misma direccion en memoria

Por otro lado quita el

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

no deberias `NUNCA` ante un error devolver un valor por defecto porque despues no te enteras si algo esta fallando

O al menos implementa un mecanismo de log a un archivo del mensaje del error

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ayudo bastante a como ordenarme. En cuanto a mi problema se resumia en la falta de llave en la tabla.